# Using GetComponent<>() with a variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm trying to create a targeting system.

When I click on a skeleton enemy I want to be able to access the health and damage from the skeleton script and likewise, when I click on a different enemy, I want to get **their** specific health and damage.

The only way I can think of doing this is using the `GetComponent` method, but is there a way to use a generic `GetComponent` that uses a variable depending on what enemy I have targeted so I can get the data of a selected enemy based on that variable?

Comment: Have you tried `EnemyScript enemyScript = gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyScript>();`?

Comment: I've done something like this: `opponent.GetComponent<Skeleton>().getHit(damage);`This is where I have hard coded in the `<ScriptName>` but I'm saying, how can i set that `<ScriptName>` equal to the `opponent`'s script?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. My suggestion is to let all enemies have the same script, so you don't need to change the <ScriptName>. Instead, in the enemy script you need to have a variable `type` for example to mark what that enemy is (eg. `type = 1` for robot, `type = 2` for alien, etc). That way you can also get the `type` from `GetComponent<ScriptName>` and make conditions for each types of enemy.

Comment: Does the GetComponent methed have an override that accepts a `System.Type` object?

Answer (score 4):

You do not show any example code, so it's hard to see what you have and have not worked out, but this is one way of approaching the problem.

```
//Pseudocode 
GameObject enemy = GetEnemy(); //This could be a raycast, collision or some other method.
Health enemyHealth = enemy.GetComponent<Health>();
```

It's really quite simple.  Another approach might to be to send a message, and let the enemy handle it if appropriate.  [From the docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void ApplyDamage(float damage) {
        print(damage);
    }
    void Example() {
        gameObject.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", 5.0F);
    }
}
```

From the sounds of it the problem you're having isn't getting the other component, ***but that you're mixing a bunch of unrelated functionalities together.***  An enemy `gameobject` should generally speaking* have the same `health component` as the main player.  Health code should not be in the `Enemy` and the `Player` and the `Destructible Box` components otherwise not only are you writing the same code many times over, you have difficulties interacting with the different implementations of the same thing.

> * *In advanced situations, the may be a valid need to have multiple implementations of a health script instead of a single huge class.  In these situations some sort of abstraction is useful - e.g. interface, inheritance or message passing.*

Comment: Good answer, the component based architecture makes this kind of stuff very easy.